# A series of three is 'trilogy'. A series of two is______?

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests

I am looking for a word that describes **a series** of two. 'Duo' isn't quite what I need. It should more be in line with 'trio', 'quartet', and so on.

I am looking for a word that would contain the same connotation of 'continuity' where one component depends on its predecessor to be understood and appreciated, but for a number of two things.

Comment: Sequel, prequel, companion, and pair have been used. Set is also fine for two (e.g. a set of dentures is comprised of two pieces).

Comment: The only possible word for this is a ...'bi-ology'?

Comment: Bilogy, if you follow the Greek structure.

Comment: ... "an unfinished trilogy."

Comment: This question was referenced in *[episode 581](https://twit.tv/shows/security-now/episodes/581)* (2016-10-11) of podcast *Security Now*, at 1 h 32 min 00 secs - 1 h 33 min 50 secs.

Comment: Obviously, just as [*Mostly Harmless*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mostly_Harmless) is "The fifth book in the increasingly inaccurately named *Hitchhiker Trilogy*", you've got an *under-performing trilogy*.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

### Diptychs, dilogies, duologies, series, cycles, and sagas

**TL;DR:**  Use ***diptych*** for one novel published in two halves, ***dilogy*** or ***duology*** for two completely different but still ordered novels, but just ***series*** when ordering doesn’t matter. Less commonly used words for related collections include ***cycle, saga***, and ***legendarium***.

---

Actually, a series of three may **or may not** be a trilogy —  it just depends. It might just be a [three-part serial](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serial_(literature)).

The word *trilogy* was originally applied to a set of three completely separate but interrelated Greek plays. Our best surviving example of these is the [*Oresteia*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oresteia) by Aeschylus about the House of Atreus (the Atreides, in one spelling), which comprised three different plays: *Agamemnon*,  *The Libation Bearers*, and *The Eumenides*.  The satyr play *Proteus*, which served as a sort of coda piece (well, or codpiece :) to the trilogy, has not survived.

So that’s three. But what about two?

The word most directly analogous to *trilogy* is not the neologued *duology* but rather ***dilogy***. However, that has not historically meant a two-volume set of novels. Per the OED, *dilogy* is a term of rhetoric meaning:

> Etymology: ad. L. *dilogia* ambiguity, a. Gr. *διλογία*, f. *δίλογος*, f. *δι‑* twice + *‑λογος* speaking. In mod.Fr. *dilogie*.
>
> 1. The use of an ambiguous or equivocal expression; the word or expression so used.
> 2. Repetition of a word or phrase, in the same context. In recent Dicts.

If that ambiguity of sense does not bother you, then go ahead and use *dilogy*.

Author Dan Simmons often writes [what he calls ***diptychs***](http://www.dansimmons.com/news/news_items_sept.htm), stories published in two halves, like two opposing leaves folded into one tale, such as his *[Ilium](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ilium_(novel))–[Olympos](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Olympos_(novel))* diptych.   Unlike *duology* but like *dilogy* and *trilogy*, ***diptych*** is an authentic Greek word.

However, rather than meaning two different words as a putative *duology* would appear to indicate, ***diptych*** means a “two-folded thing”, analogous to a ***triptych*** meaning a “three-folded thing”.  So a *diptych* is one piece folded into two halves.

These are not merely two novels occurring in the same world setting; they are two integral halves of the same thing. They might perhaps be called a series in that *Ilium* is the first half of the singular story concluded in *Olympos*.

Another example of a diptych by a different author is the [*The Wizard Knight*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Wizard_Knight) by Gene Wolfe. These were originally published in two parts, first *Knight* then *Wizard*, but the work is now available as one volume.

Another of Wolfe’s works, [*The Book of the New Sun*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Book_of_the_New_Sun), has been variously published as four volumes, as two volumes, and as one volume.  One might call the two-volume set a *diptych* were one so inclined, or the four-volume set a ***tetraptych***. But that will probably just get you talked about — and probably more, alas, than the incorrect ***tetralogy*** would. Maybe just go for the jocular ***fourology***; at least nobody will ever bother to tell you that that one is wrong. :)

Interestingly, just as Aeschylus had an extra coda to his *Oresteia* in the lost *Proteus*, Wolfe relented to his publisher’s pressure by issuing *The Urth of the New Sun* as a follow-on novel. But Wolfe himself calls it a *coda*. It is a second novel following the first, and even published as five volumes these do not a pentalogy make.

Perhaps the most notoriously mislabelled example is [*The Lord of the Rings*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Lord_of_the_Rings), a single novel that has seen publication in one single volume, in three volumes, and [in seven volumes](http://www.tolkienbooks.net/php/gallery.php?subsection=78).  No matter how you look at it, *The Lord of the Rings* is never a trilogy nor heptalogy; it is only a single novel, just like a diptych is. Tolkien himself famously wrote that “of course” *The Lord of the Rings* was no trilogy, since he actually understood the difference. No matter how many pieces a novel is published in, it is still a novel.

The distinguishing factor is that they make up one contiguous story, and must be read in that order.  They might as well have been published as one volume, but for publishing constraints of size and timeliness.  On the other hand, the combination of *The Hobbit* and *The Lord of the Rings* might be justly called a dilogy, since they are two independent novels that can be read each on their own.

An interesting case containing both example and counterexample is the [*d’Artagnan Romances*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/D%27Artagnan_Romances), a trilogy by Alexander Dumas. The trilogy’s three novels are *The Three Musketeers*, *Twenty Years After*, and *The Vicomte of Bragelonne*.

That is a legitimate trilogy, as the novels are separate stories. However, the last of those three novels is so large that it has been variously published in sets of three, four, and even five volumes. (You may recognize *The Man in the Iron Mask*, one of the pieces of the third novel.) *Vicomte* is all still one novel though, not any sort of ***whatchamacallogy***.

Steven Brust would later mimic Dumas’s structure of a trilogy whose third novel is published in three volumes in Brust’s own [*Khaavren Romances*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Khaavren_Romances), an overt homage to the earlier swashbuckling trilogy of Dumas.  Brust’s trilogy comprises *The Phoenix Guards*, *Five Hundred Years After*, and *The Viscount of Adrilankha*.  However, *Viscount* was itself published as a triptych of three parts, each under its own title, just as Dumas’s earlier *Vicomte* had been.

When you have two or three different self-contained stories in the same setting, this is something else.  If they are expected to be read in a particular serial order, then they are perhaps a dilogy or trilogy, although it is pointless to the point of obscurantism to keep adding Greek prefixes to *‑logy* as further volumes are issued. If you dare call the thirteen Vlad Taltos novels from *Jhereg* through *Tiassa* published by Steven Brust through 2011 a ***triskaidekalogy***, you had best be doing so in jest, because no one will take you seriously. They are merely a ***series***, and therefore need be read in no particular order.  Another modern series that can be read in any order is the [*Culture Series*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Culture_series) by the late Iain Banks.

But when they are just one story that happens to be published separately in a number of volumes, they are not a trilogy nor even a series. They are merely a serial, or a serialized novel.  [Many novels were originally published this way](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serial_(literature)).

### The key point is that a single novel split into three pieces is never a trilogy, nor is a single novel split into two pieces a dilogy or duology.

They are just [serialized novels](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serial_(literature)). Words like ***diptych*** for a two-parter and ***triptych*** for a three-parter are much more accurate than *duology* or *trilogy*, since those imply that they are separate novels — separate words, if you will — not merely one thing with two or three folds.

Sometimes you come across larger collections of written works that all occur in the same setting, but may not include the same characters or time periods.  Often these contain not just several different series of novels but also shorter works such as novellas, short stories, annals or histories, and sometimes even poetry.  Taken as a whole, these are each called a ***cycle***.  Taken from a Greek word originally meaning circle, the term was first used in the context of Homeric epics, then of Arthurian ones, and finally found itself applied to later great works of modern writers.  The OED defines this sense of *cycle* as:

> A series of poems or prose romances, collected round or relating to a central event or epoch of mythic history and forming a continuous narrative; as the ***Arthurian cycle***. Also *transf*.
>
> Originally used in the ***Epic cycle*** Gr. *ὁ(ἑπικὸς) κύκλος*, the series of epic poems written by later poets (*Cyclic poets*) to complete Homer, and presenting (with the Iliad and Odyssey) a continuous history of the Trojan war and of all the heroes engaged in it.

So for example, the [*Mabinogion*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mabinogion) is a cycle of eleven stories, the earliest ones we have of the Britons.  In a modern context, the tales of Sherlock Holmes by Arthur Conan Doyle are sometimes called the *Holmes Cycle*, and the P.G. Wodehouse novels and stories about Jeeves and Wooster are occasionally called the *Jeeves Cycle*.

More recently, the collection of three different series and numerous ancillary shorter works that Gene Wolfe has produced in the setting begun in *The Book of the New Sun* and followed on in *The Book of the Long Sun* and *The Book of the Short Sun* is sometimes referred to as  *The Solar Cycle*, while the two series, one separate novel, and several shorter works that Steven Brust has produced in the Vlad and Khaavren universe is sometimes referred to as *The Dragaeran Cycle*.

Tolkien preferred to call the aggregate collection of his tales of Middle-earth his [*Legendarium*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tolkien%27s_legendarium), a Medieval Latin word meaning a collection of legends.  To the best of my knowledge, this word is today used exclusively for Tolkien’s world, not for anyone else’s.

Related narratives that are more Nordic in origin or tone are sometimes known as ***sagas***.  The Icelandic Sagas collected by [Snorri Sturluson](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snorri_Sturluson) are a prototypical example. Modern examples of collections called sagas include Julian May’s [*Saga of the Pliocene Exiles*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saga_of_Pliocene_Exile) and Lois McMaster Bujold’s [*Vorkosigan Saga*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vorkosigan_Saga).

Comment: One should be exercise caution in describing any kind of literary work as a di- or triptych, since the listener is likely to take both words to refer to their overwhelmingly most common meanings, namely a **picture/painting** separated into three panels. (_Diptychs_ is apparently also used in some kind of church context, but I have no idea about that, and it doesn’t seem likely to be confused with artwork or literary works in practice.)

Comment: Thanks Tchrist--that was a mouthful, but interesting. I've worked in publishing, and we often use the word "duet" to describe a 2 book series.

Comment: I wonder whether *tri-* referred to a certain style of embedding episodes like allegories in a framing narrative, for which *three* might just be the most common count (e.g. in a christmas carol). Grimm's can be justly called a cycle in the sense of collection, cp. *encyclopedia*; The Mabigonion is also a collection, but the original Parcival might well have been a trilogy; at least it has a framing narrative I believe. Lessing's novel Nathan has one embedded story: the ring parable recounts three sons. There needs to be something to justify adding *-ology*, which effectively means *teaching*.

Comment: ... to be precise, I hypothesise *tri-* came to mean *three* more or less by accident, though I don't know any other root for *tri-*, but there's no internal derivation for the PIE root, so one may guess, and there's no shortage of numerologic suggestions for various original (disingenious) derivations.

Answer (score 6):

[Duology](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/duology) is possible. For example, [Time Duology by Nora Roberts](http://books.google.com/books/about/The_Time_Duology_by_Nora_Roberts.html?id=tR6ehwJgm1wC).

Answer (score 3):

I suggest that diptych is probably the most reasonable answer for books, even though the most common usage of the word does indeed refer to paintings displayed as hinged panels. Nonetheless, the word diptych does have usage with respect to books and seems to be common terminology in the publishing field.

The accepted answer by @tchrist is certainly the most complete. My only comment is regarding the definition of diptych as a "two-folded thing." In reality, every diptych has two leaves and a single fold. I suspect the two-folded phrasing originates with a literal interpretation of the etymology. My dictionary defines diptych as a "hinged two-leaved tablet". It gives the etymology as "diptych(a) writing tablet with two leaves" from the Latin, which derives from the Greek "plural of diptychos folded together". The Greek diptychos breaks down into "di- plus ptych(e) a fold". If the latter is translated literally it yields two folds, which is obviously incorrect.

Comment: The definition of *ptyche* is naive (not wrong per se but potentially misleading) and the etymology is uncertain. *pt-* is certainly a typologically extraordinary consonant cluster. *folding* might seem an obviously related verb for what it's worth in English, but not quite so in many other languages. In German we *slay* our books open and slam them shut (viz "auf- und zu-schlagen", cp Danish *sla* "to bolt"; also *-klappen*). Incidentally, AGreek has *tupto* "to strike, hit". I don't say that's the root, but a derived sense "to divide, part" seems reasonable in either case. Just my two cents.

Comment: In other news, "twofold" is very much comparable, only reading it as "two folds, wrinkles, seams" seems problematic.

Comment: Thanks, vectory. I'd say your two cents is worth at least two bits. :)