# Words for movie/book/etc series with more than four items?

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice

As discussed in this [other english.SE post](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/210177/a-series-of-three-is-trilogy-a-series-of-two-is), dilogy/duology/etc. can be used to describe a series of two items, and trilogy and tetralogy exist for three- and four-item series, but I couldn't find any words for series with more than four items.

Specifically, I'd like to see words for up to eight-length series. (The thought came about when trying to find a word other than saga/series/etc. to describe the Harry Potter book and movie series.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

How about just continuing the **series**?

[*Trilogy*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/trilogy), [*tetralogy*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/tetralogy), *[pentalogy](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/pentalogy)*, *[hexalogy](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/hexalogy)*, *[heptalogy](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/heptalogy)*, *[octalogy](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/octalogy)*, etc.

Comment: @alwayslearning Good point. What's going on here is that *-logy"* means oral or written expression (Merriam-Webster), and *penta-*, *hexa-*, etc. are from the Greek for *five*, *six*, etc. Note that NVZ was kind enough to add links to my answer. NVZ, thank you. Much appreciated. I need to learn how to do that better. I'm still -- and always -- learning also. :-)

Comment: @RichardKayser you can add links like this: `[title](link)`. For example, `[Google](google.com)`

Comment: Thanks Richard, exactly what I was looking for! Now back to the Harry Potter octalogy of movies :P

Comment: @DolanAntenucci Enjoy! The best octalogy of all time? :-)

Comment: Shouldn't it be spelled *[octology](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=octalogy%2C+octology&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Coctology%3B%2Cc0)*, the prefix being [octo-](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/octo-)? [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/octalogy) has it wrong, but usage seems to get it right.

Comment: @PeterShor There’s a lot of variation between _octo-_ and _octa-_, both in Greek, Latin, and English. A simple Google search (searching for _"octology" -octalogy_ and vice versa) gives about 14,000 hits for _octology_ and 22,000 for _octalogy_. _"Harry Potter octalogy"_ gives 14,000 hits too; _"Harry Potter octology"_ gives only 44 (!). Ngrams have only _octology_. My COCA account has reached its quota, so I can’t compare there; of UK corpora, both appear in WIKI-EN and no others, with _octology_ being about ten times more common. Not entirely sure what to make of all that, but both exist.